# Django is loading static files but not image that are stored from backend in production

Tags: django, production, django-staticfiles

As the title says, after I changed DEBUG to False, the image that is uploaded from the admin panel are not loading. However, other static files like css files and images that are loaded only from HTML side are rendered properly.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('marathon.urls', namespace='homepage')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**html file that renders image**

```
    <div class="js-billboard">
        {% for slide in slider %}
            <div class="billboard__item">
                <figure><img src="{{ slide.image.url }}" alt="Mountain Marathon"></figure>
                <div class="billboard__detail">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                            <div class="col-12 cell">
                                <h2>{{ slide.title }}</h2>
                                <p><span>{{ slide.description }}</span></p>
                                <a href="{{ slide.link }}" class="button">{{ slide.link_title }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: add your html file and you projects main urls.py file

Comment: @Shreyash I have updated the code. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the following line of code in your projects `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please note that `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` for your **media urls** will only be added to your urlpatterns list if `DEBUG=True` in this case. Django doesn't serve media files in Production or when the `DEBUG=False`

I would suggest using a online storage API like AWS3, cloudinary or even firebase. These do offer the capability of serving media files whether `DEBUG=True` or `DEBUG=False`.

Comment: I used whitenoise but after adding this line 
`STATICFILES_STORAGE = whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`
I get server error (500)

Comment: Is AWS3 free to use?

Comment: Is your site in production as we speak?

Comment: AWS3 I think you're required to pay... However, I'd suggest using Cloudinary, this is my personal preference by the way. You get 25GB free and to get more you'd have to pay for it. That's what I use.

Comment: I am taking it to production. I will look at Cloudinary and see if it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay no problem. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I used cloudinary as you mentioned and it worked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You're welcome mate :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

add this in your main your urls.py folder and create a forlder name staic cdn in you main project and in your settings.py

```
STATIC_CDN = BASE_DIR / 'static_cdn'

and in bottom 

STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_CDN

# MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and then run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

in your terminal what it will do it will create copy of you static file in your static cdn folder because cloud base storage look your static or media file in you cdn folder
and make sure you install pillow

and tell me if you still getting error

Comment: I am using whitenoise and have this setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'` which produces missing fonts files error (they are not missing though) when collectstatic is run. However when the above whitenoise setting is commented out, the static files are working but media files are not.

Comment: I did it as you mentioned and for media handling used cloudinary and it worked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JoyboySharma if you find answer right please accept it this help other

Comment: Both of the answers helped me however I fix using Cloudinary, so I will mark the other answer since I can not mark both the answers. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: no problem just accept someone answer okay everytime when you find anwser is right